# Create a Proxy from an instance of Entity

Tags: entity-framework-core, ef-core-3.1

I'm using EntityFramework Core 3.1 with LazyLoadingProxies, my Entity implements ICloneable, and I need to convert the Cloned entity into a Proxy to enable lazy loading...

```
var model = await DatabaseContext.Set<MyEntity>()
  .SingleAsync(m => m.Id.Equals(id));

var clone = model.Clone();

// this would be ideal, but CreateProxy only takes ConstructorArguments
// I'd rather use ICloneable than have constructors that take an Entity
//var clone = DatabaseContext.CreateProxyFrom(model.Clone());
```

Is there any way to create a proxy from an instance of MyEntity?